# "Groupie" Therapy

Tags: knowledge

This is a list of *groups.*

The letters of each group's name are indicated with underscores(_), words separated by hyphens(-).

As these are *groups* (containing more than one item), *most* will end in an **s**, and this pluralization is given where warranted.

The list of letters that follow the names are the first letter(s) of each member of that group. These letters are not *necessarily* in traditional order (if such traditional order even exists).

All groups are *finite* and *complete* AFAIK unless otherwise noted (‡).

***Example:***
_ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ s
{S, S, T, T S}
Answer: Human - Sense*s*
Group: {Sight, Sound, Taste, Touch, Smell}

---

---

1: _ _ _ s
{M, T, T, W, F, S, S}

---

2: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{A, A, NA, A, A, SA, E}

---

3: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s †
{NA, A, SA, I, NP, SP, A}

---

4: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
{K, P, C, O, F, G, S}

---

5: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{M, B, F, R, A, I}

---

6: _ _ _ _ _ _ s †
{M, V, E, M, J, S, U, N}

---

7: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ s
{O, G, I, V, R, Y, B}

---

8: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s
{L, G, G, S, W, E, P}

---

9: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{C, T, C, D, P, K, H}

---

10: _ _ _ _ _ s
{J, M, M, J, S, N, F, A, J, A, O, D}

---

11: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ s ‡
{Ra, D, GM, G, MO, f, R, BG, h, JZ}

---

BONUS: _ _ _ _ _  -  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{D, C, SS, BT, AC, P, RC, DS, HV, M, PU}

---

---

† Modern Definition
‡ Incomplete, only current "Top Ten" shown

Comment: Is there a pun in "groupie" 

Comment: This is one of my favorite puzzles in a while!

Comment: Is it strange that so many have 7 items? This was not on purpose, I just noticed. (BTW, it was surprisingly hard to come up with items that were (mostly) finite *and* complete... Try it!

Comment: @Chowzen [Obligatory (spoilery?) xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1417/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Community Wiki Answer

**PLEASE** cast appreciation votes for these answers (and perhaps the question itself ) on the individual answers themselves as linked below.

1: _ _ _ s
{M, T, T, W, F, S, S}

> Days:
> Monday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

[Ans: floraline](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65249#65249)

---

2: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{A, A, NA, A, A, SA, E}

> Continents:
> Africa, Asia, North America, Antarctica, Australia, South America, Europe

[Ans: Daniel Schepler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65250#65250)

---

3: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s †
{NA, A, SA, I, NP, SP, A}

> Seven-seas:
> North Atlantic, Artic, South Atlantic, Indian, North Pacific, South Pacific, Antarctic

[Ans: QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65254#65254)

---

4: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
{K, P, C, O, F, G, S}

> Biological Taxonomy:
> Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus, Species

[Ans: ABcDexter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65251#65251)

---

5: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{M, B, F, R, A, I}

> Animal Classes:
> Mammal, Bird, Fish, Reptile, Amphibian, Invertebrates

[Ans: hagfy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65256#65256)

---

6: _ _ _ _ _ _ s †
{M, V, E, M, J, S, U, N}

> Planets:
> Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune

[Ans: floraline](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65249#65249)

---

7: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ s
{O, G, I, V, R, Y, B}

> Rainbow Colors:
> Orange, Green, Indigo, Violet, Red, Yellow, Blue

[Ans: floraline](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65249#65249)

---

8: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s
{L, G, G, S, W, E, P}

> Deadly-Sins:
> Lust, Greed, Gluttony, Sloth, Wrath, Envy, Pride

[Ans: TwoBitOperation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65255#65255)

---

9: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{C, T, C, D, P, K, H}

> Heavenly Virtues:
> Chastity, Temperance, Charity, Diligence, Patience, Kindness, Humility

[Ans: TwoBitOperation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65255#65255)

---

10: _ _ _ _ _ s
{J, M, M, J, S, N, F, A, J, A, O, D}

> Months:
> January, May, March, June, September, November, February, April, July, August, October, December

[Ans: floraline](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65249#65249)

---

11: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ s ‡
{Ra, D, GM, G, MO, f, R, BG, h, JZ}

> Puzzling Users:
> Rand al'Thor, Deusovi, Gareth McCaughan, Gamow, M Oehm, f'', Rubio, Beastly Gerbil, hexomino, Joe Z

[Ans: Reinier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65253#65253)

---

BONUS: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{D, C, SS, BT, AC, P, RC, DS, HV, M, PU}

> These Questions
> :
>  Days, Continents, Seven Seas, Biological Taxonomy, Animal Classes, Planets, Rainbow colors, Deadly sins, Heavenly Virtues, Months, Puzzling Users

[Ans: Reinier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/groupie-therapy/65253#65253)

---

Answer (score 20):

11: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ s ‡
{Ra, D, GM, G, MO, f, R, BG, h, JZ}

> Puzzling-Users
> {Rand al'Thor, Deusovi, Gareth McCaughan, Gamow, M Oehm, f'', Rubio, Beastly Gerbil, hexomino, Joe Z.}

BONUS: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{D, C, SS, BT, AC, P, RC, DS, HV, M, PU}

> These-Questions
> {Days, Continents, Seven-Seas, Biological-Taxonomy, Animal-Classes, Planets, Rainbow-Colors, Deadly-Sins, Heavenly-Virtues, Months, Puzzling-Users}

Comment: Nice job there :)

Comment: Answer #11 is correct.  (Fixed the Dyslexic clue, Thakns!);

Comment: Bonus is correct, though I was going for rot13(Gurfr Dhrfgvbaf).

Comment: I have edited it in now, and completed the list

Answer (score 14):

What I have so far

1: _ _ _ s
{M, T, T, W, F, S, S}

> Days
> Monday, Tuesday, Thursday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

5: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{M, B, F, R, A, I}

> Degree Leagues
> Master's, Bachelor's, First Professional, Research, Associate, Intermediate Graduate Qualifications

6: _ _ _ _ _ _ s †
{M, V, E, M, J, S, U, N}

> Planets
> Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune

7: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ s
{O, G, I, V, R, Y, B}

> Rainbow colors
> Orange, Green, Indigo, Violet, Red, Yellow, Blue

10: _ _ _ _ _ s
{J, M, M, J, S, N, F, A, J, A, O, D}

> Months
> January, March, May, June, September, November, February, April, July, August, October, December

Comment: 1,6,7,10 work, but I don't think that your answer to 5 could be "finite and complete."

Comment: Technically they are the rot13(fvk pngrtbevrf bs qrterrf erpbtavmrq va gur HF), but I see your point, and it doesn't fit the rot13(obahf pyhr NP).

Comment: The abbreviations would have been {M, B, FP, R, A, IGQ}, in keeping with the format...

Answer (score 13):

2: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s {A, A, NA, A, A, SA, E}

> Continents (Asia, Africa, North America, Antarctica, Australia, South America, Europe)

Comment: Answer #2 is correct.

Answer (score 13):

One that Floraline hasn't answered yet:

4: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  {K, P, C, O, F, G, S}

> Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus, Species
>  **biological taxonomy** (taxonomy order Mnemonic)

Comment: This looks good, probably the phrase to fit the blanks is rot13(ovbybtvpny gnkbabzl).

Comment: Answer #4 is correct.

Comment: Useful to include the expansion of {K, P, C, O, F, G, S}

Answer (score 13):

Is 5: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s {M, B, F, R, A, I} :

> Animal-Classes?

Edit: Listing them out:

> Mammal, Bird, Fish, Reptile, Amphibian, Invertebrate

Comment: Answer #5 is correct. Spell them out for your +1. :)

Answer (score 12):

Got 8: {L, G, G, S, W, E, P}

> Deadly Sins

<strike>Working on 9, which I think is the last unsolved one at this point..</strike>

And 9:{C, T, C, D, P, K, H}

> Heavenly Virtues

Comment: We are still missing #5

Comment: @floraline Ah, OK.  Thought you had 5 but I see the comment now

Comment: It looks like the correct answer has now been given, I think we are all done!

Answer (score 9):

Is 3

> The 7 seas?

So,

> Arctic, North Atlantic, South Atlantic, North Pacific, South Pacific, Indian, and Southern Oceans

Comment: Answer #3 is correct, [is known also by ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Ocean)

Answer (score 0):

Collected all the answers into one.

1: _ _ _ s
{M, T, T, W, F, S, S}

> Days:
> Monday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

2: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{A, A, NA, A, A, SA, E}

> Continents:
> Africa, Asia, North America, Antarctica, Australia, South America, Europe

3: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s †
{NA, A, SA, I, NP, SP, A}

> Seven-seas:
> North Atlantic, Artic, South Atlantic, Indian, North Pacific, South Pacific, Antarctic

4: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
{K, P, C, O, F, G, S}

> Biological Taxonomy:
> Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus, Species

5: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{M, B, F, R, A, I}

> Animal Classes:
> Mammal, Bird, Fish, Reptile, Amphibian, Invertebrates

6: _ _ _ _ _ _ s †
{M, V, E, M, J, S, U, N}

> Planets:
> Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune

7: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ s
{O, G, I, V, R, Y, B}

> Rainbow Colors:
> Orange, Green, Indigo, Violet, Red, Yellow, Blue

8: _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ s
{L, G, G, S, W, E, P}

> Deadly-Sins:
> Lust, Greed, Gluttony, Sloth, Wrath, Envy, Pride

9: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{C, T, C, D, P, K, H}

> Heavenly Virtues:
> Chastity, Temperance, Charity, Diligence, Patience, Kindness, Humility

10: _ _ _ _ _ s
{J, M, M, J, S, N, F, A, J, A, O, D}

> Months:
> January, May, March, June, September, November, February, April, July, August, October, December

11: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ s ‡
{Ra, D, GM, G, MO, f, R, BG, h, JZ}

> Puzzling Users:
> Rand al'Thor, Deusovi, Gareth McCaughan, Gamow, M Oehm, f'', Rubio, Beastly Gerbil, hexomino, Joe Z

BONUS: _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
{D, C, SS, BT, AC, P, RC, DS, HV, M, PU}

> These Questions
> :
>  Days, Continents, Seven Seas, Biological Taxonomy, Animal Classes, Planets, Rainbow colors, Deadly sins, Heavenly Virtues, Months, Puzzling Users

Comment: This should be community wiki